# Modbus traffic in Wireshark

Tags: networking, python, wireshark

I am tinkering with some modbus python scripts to try and learn it but I cant seem to capture traffic on wireshark. ***Can a Modbus client and server both run localhost on the same computer listening on the same TCP port 502? Or would they have to be on separate machines?***

All running local host a client and server scripts based on [pyModbusTCP](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/index.html) which is surprisingly easy getting this up and working on Python 3.9 Windows 10.

These two scripts are from the examples of the pyModbusTCP repo I am just running them locally on my Windows 10 machine to see if I can view the traffic on Wireshark. Pip install the package and this code will work:

***client.py***

```
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
import time

c = ModbusClient(host="localhost",
                 port=502,auto_open=True,
                 auto_close=False)


# main read loop
while True:
    # read 10 bits (= coils) at address 0, store result in coils list
    coils_l = c.read_coils(0, 10)

    # if success display registers
    if coils_l:
        print('coil ad #0 to 9: %s' % coils_l)
    else:
        print('unable to read coils')

    # sleep 2s before next polling
    time.sleep(2)
```

***server.py***

```
import argparse
from pyModbusTCP.server import ModbusServer, DataHandler
from pyModbusTCP.constants import EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION


# some const
ALLOW_R_L = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.10']
ALLOW_W_L = ['127.0.0.1']


# a custom data handler with IPs filter
class MyDataHandler(DataHandler):
    def read_coils(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_coils(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def read_d_inputs(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_d_inputs(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def read_h_regs(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_h_regs(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def read_i_regs(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_i_regs(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def write_coils(self, address, bits_l, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_W_L:
            return super().write_coils(address, bits_l, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def write_h_regs(self, address, words_l, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_W_L:
            return super().write_h_regs(address, words_l, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', type=str, default='localhost', help='Host (default: localhost)')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=502, help='TCP port (default: 502)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # init modbus server and start it
    server = ModbusServer(host=args.host, port=args.port, data_hdl=MyDataHandler())
    server.start()
```

On Wireshark am definitely a newbie here but selecting my ethernet adapter there is definitely traffic:
[image]

Then attempting to filter for modbus tcp.port 502 nothing comes up...any ideas to try?
[image]

The scripts appear to be working as client script console prints:

```
coil ad #0 to 9: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 9: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 9: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am tinkering with some modbus python scripts to try and learn it but I cant seem to capture traffic on wireshark. Can a Modbus client and server both run localhost on the same computer listening on the same TCP port 502? Or would they have to be on separate machines?

The TCP client **does not listen** on TCP port 502 – it only connects *to* the server's port 502. (Usually the client-side port in TCP is randomly chosen, so the module doesn't even have a parameter for it.) It should generally work the same way as hosting a web server on localhost.

> On Wireshark am definitely a newbie here but selecting my ethernet adapter there is definitely traffic:

This looks like HTTPS traffic (some TLS and some QUIC on port 443).

> Then attempting to filter for modbus tcp.port 502 nothing comes up

Since you're connecting to the same machine, your traffic doesn't actually go through any external Ethernet interface (even if you're using its IP address) – it's treated the same way as 'localhost' traffic.

So your TCP packets might show up on the "Loopback" interface instead – though capturing loopback packets on Windows doesn't always work well.